Cannot use the Site module in SFCC OCAPI Hooks
I am working with SFCC OCAPI After Hook dw.ocapi.data.customer_list.customers.afterPUT. The afterHook function triggers a service payload function that generates customer payload data. To generate the payload the dw.system.Site module is used. However, the function throws an error because the dw.system.Site module is not accessible inside this hook. How can I troubleshoot this issue and use the dw.system.Site module to generate the payload?
The afterHook function looks like this :-
importPackage(dw.system);
importPackage(dw.customer);

var Logger = require('dw/system/Logger');
var AccountCreationHelper = require('storefront_core/cartridge/scripts/helper/AccountCreationHelper');

/**
 * The function executes after the customer is created using the OCAPI endpoint.
 *
 * @param {Object} customer - the new customer.
 * @param {Object} create - the customer create document.
 * @param {string} customerListId - the id of the customerlist the customer is assigned to.
 */
exports.afterPut = function (customer, create, customerListId) {
    var customerData = {};
    customerData.object = customer;
    var isVoucherSubscribed = customerData.object.profile.custom.isVoucherSubscribed;

    // Sends the new customer data to Braze Onbaording Journey.
    AccountCreationHelper.sfmcCreateAccount(customerData, isVoucherSubscribed, null, true, false);
}

AccountCreationHelper.sfmcCreateAccount function is where the site module is used.
OCAPI settings is configured Global context.
Tried different ways to use the Site module in the hook function.
